# GoLang yaml unmarshal - updating structs

Tags: go, struct, yaml

I use https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml library to parse yaml settings file.
The settings struct needs to change slightly.

The current struct is

```
type Settings struct{
   Hosts []string
}
```

The new struct should be

```
type Host struct {
   URL  string
   Name string
}
type Settings struct{
   Hosts []Host
}
```

Current yaml:

```
hosts:
-http://server1.com
-http://server2.com
```

The new yaml will be

```
hosts:
- url:http://server1.com
  name:s1
- url:http://server2.com
  name:s2
```

I don't want to force users to go and update the yaml file after the change is implemented. How can I parse both files (new and old)? For example, if the old file is received, I want name field to be empty. If the new file is received then I will take whatever is provided.

Thanks!

Comment: In the new Settings Hosts will be an array of Host struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Correct way** would be to release *v2* of your package for new structure of `Settings`. Users of v2 can use new structure and existing users can keep using old structure with v1 of your package.

If this is not possible then another way is to declare Settings as array of empty interface.

```
type Settings struct{
   Hosts []interface{}
}
```

yaml will parse ok with this, and you will get data in Hosts fields as

1. array of `string` for old yaml
2. array of `map[string]interface{}` for new yaml

type assertion will be needed to parse that into new struct or old struct.

**Note** the type of Hosts will always be `[]interface{}`, it is the elements whose type will need to be asserted to populate the fields.

Comment: That's pretty much what I came up with. I added new field Hosts2 into settings. First field became []Host and the other one []interface{}. Parsing is done into the field []interface{}, then I loop through the objects and check their type. The old format is always a string and the new format can be converted into a map. Thanks.